# how to set watson online chat applicatiom to my website

Tags: wordpress, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

Anyone knows how to connect an IBM Watson chatbot to a website? I am using bluemix. I already have a watson conversation and I want to integrate it to my wordpress website. I'm not understanding where to include the configurations.

Comment: are you makeing the application through noodejs?

Answer (score 1):

Watson Conversation is just a REST API endpoint. Youll need some widget that calls the service as outlined here:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#create_workspace

 We have some sample chat widgets you could potentially embed as an iframe or something if you want. 

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/sample-applications.html

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-bot

Comment: @user94 see yogescicak's answer for a ready-made plugin.This will enable you to easily deploy a chatbot on your WordPress site. No coding required.

Comment: Wordpress plugins are great for broad technological acceptance but I have yet to find a straightforward tutorial/howto that explains with examples how to incorporate a watson conversation into a simple vanilla website. Does such a resource yet exist?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Watson Conversation WordPress plugin that you can use to deploy your chatbot to a Wordpress site.

The plugin is called “Watson conversation.”

You can find the configurations steps here: https://courses.cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:CognitiveClass+CB0103EN+v1/courseware/c6143d9ff5764057a91e53fa8a3a6dff/2b860fc913a745e29dce92bf72d15faf/

The Watson Conversation plugin can be installed both on self-hosted WordPress installations and hosted WordPress (on WordPress.com). WordPress.com charges a fee to allow us to install custom plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a simple method (Simple, but paid) and use [chatlio](https://chatlio.com/app/#/settings/install).
This way you can just install the plugin to your wordpress.

IBM makes available too the [web application](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple), but it's in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Watson provides a web chat plugin which can be embedded to the website
Visit
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-chat#
to get the script code and paste the code as close to the closing  tag as possible.

Another way is to integrate with [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/). Go to Bot integration section, select IBM Watson, enter your Watson API key. Then copy the script from Settings -> Install to your website code before the closing  tag.